# autofac module resolve config WebApi N Layer

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm used simple autofac its working, but in module scan option from assembly it thrown run time exception in Web Api.

Simple Working Code in Global.asax.cs

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
builder.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(config);
builder.RegisterType<ReportRepository>().As<IReportRepository>();
builder.RegisterType<UserRepository>().As<IUserRepository>();
....
var container = builder.Build();
config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
```

Module Scan from Assembly in different layer

```
public class RepositoryModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        //var assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
        var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
                .Where(a => a.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
                .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        base.Load(builder);
    }
}
```

In Global.asax.cs

```
var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
var builder1 = new ContainerBuilder();
builder1.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
builder1.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(config);
builder1.RegisterModule(new RepositoryModule());
using (var container1 = builder1.Build())
{
    config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container1);
}
```

find problem in this or suggest any other simple method.

Thanks...

Comment: Can you provide details of the exception?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the using(). You are disposing of the container.